# How can I search for a file via keyword then attach it to an email?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, email

Also would it be possible for me to use the filename that is detected and attached to the email as the text for my email subject line?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$file = "C:\Users\me\myfilename_123.csv"
$mailboxdata = (Get-MailboxStatistics | select DisplayName, TotalItemSize,TotalDeletedItemSize, ItemCount, LastLoggedOnUserAccount, LastLogonTime)
$mailboxdata | Export-Csv "$file"
$smtpServer = "192.168.1.100"
$att = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "my@email.com"
$msg.To.Add("your@email.com")
$msg.To.Add("another@email.com")
$msg.Subject = "Notification from email server"
$msg.Body = "Attached is the email server mailbox report"
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)
$att.Dispose()

##### Search directory for keyword "myfilename", attaches the file found which
##### has a filename that includes this keyword

# $file = SEARCH "C:\Users\me\"
# IF filename contains "myfilename" ATTACH as $file

##### Message subject is set to the filename of the attachment 

$msg.Subject = "("myfilename_123)"
```

Comment: Keyword in the file name? The file content? The path? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The file name.For example look for the word "Spain" and match the file called "File about Spain" then attach this file to the email

Comment: `Get-ChildItem $rootdir -Filter "*$keyword*" -Recurse`